# Euler characteristic of Seifert surfaces

Tags: surfaces, geometric-topology, knot-theory

[image: surfaces]
For the above problem, I wanted to use the formula for surface-with-boundary with a single boundary component $\chi = 1-2g$, but I don't know how to find genus of those surfaces, can anyone help? This is in my knot theory course, sorry I don't know much about topology.

Comment: Just wondering: May someone explain to me where there are surfaces? I mean being knot-diagrams I suppose they represent embeddings of $\Bbb S^1$ into $\Bbb R^3$, so their complements are 3-manifolds with boundary, but not surfaces, right?

Comment: @PrudiiArca Surfaces are the slender parts between the curves. It's called "Seifert surface".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would say it's much easier to do these computations by noting the graph to which each surface deformation retracts, and computing the Euler characteristic of that graph.

Just as an example, (b) clearly deformation retracts to a $\theta$ graph (although in this case you have to turn $\theta$ on its side). That graph has $2$ vertices and $3$ edges so $\chi = 2-3=-1$. And then, of course, using the equation $\chi = 1-2g$, you can compute $g = 1$.

Comment: A small note it if you want to compute the genus from the Euler characteristic using this exact formula you should be careful to have checked that the surface has only 1 boundary component (which is the case in example (b) )

Comment: That's a good point in general, particularly with a link that has $\ge 2$ components. But in the case of a knot (as in each of (a), (b), (d)), the boundary of the Seifert surface is the knot itself which is connected. But in (c) there are $2$ components and so, yeah, the formula should be corrected.

Comment: Oh yes I was sure you knew that and was trying to indicate that in what I said. I was just adding this for when the original poster is trying to work through example c and/or for anyone who stumbles upon this in the future and is working with a link